# How can I efficiently dequeue custom table view cells in CellForRowAt function to avoid break Open-Closed Principle?

Tags: swift, uitableview, if-statement, design-patterns, solid-principles

I am using a tableview having 8-10 custom tableview cells currently, In Future, we are planning to add more cells.
Currently my CellForRowAt Function Looks like this

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCell
            cell.configure(data: viewModel.firstCellData)
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCell
            cell.configure(data: viewModel.secondCellData)
            cell.productSpecificationsTableViewHeight.constant = cell.productSpecificationsTableView.contentSize.height
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        }....
```

and so on.. upto 10 Cells.
I am using MVVM Pattern and getting all of the cell data from viewModel, having structs firstCellData for each property of the Table View Cell.
is there any Software Engineering principle to do this in an efficient way without modifying view controller code.

I am thinking of creating a model for each Cell and pass indexPath.row and Custom Table View Cell in that class but still I have to use if-else blocks in that model too. Is there any other efficient way to do it without continuous use of if-elseif blocks and breaking OCP.

Comment: Do each of your cells display something different?  Table Views generally are used for uniform tables of content.

Comment: @ScottThompson yes, each cell is completely different from each other, you can think of it. For eg: you can think of it like a long scrollable page with multiple type of content. I had choice of using UIScroll view vs UITableView but went with table view since Custom Cells are easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a data structure to encapsulate the knowledge of what information each row corresponds to.

Assume we want three rows with data about a dog, a cat, and a swallow:

```
enum TableStructure: CaseIterable {
    case dog
    case cat
    case swallow

    init?(row: Int) {
        if row < TableStructure.allCases.count {
            TableStructure.allCases[row]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var cellIdentifier: String {
        switch self {
            case .dog: return "DogCell"
            case .cat: return "CatCell"
            case .swallow: return "SwallowCell"
        }
    }
}
```

The `TableStructure` enum knows what rows I have and in which order they should appear.  I can use that in my `UITableDataSource` to better capture my intent:

```
class TableViewDelegate : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return TableStructure.allCases.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cellSource = TableStructure(row: indexPath.row) {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellSource.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
            switch cellSource {
            case .dog:
                configureCell(cell: cell as! DogCell, model: viewModel.dogData)
            case .cat:
                configureCell(cell: cell as! CatCell, model: viewModel.catData)
            case .swallow:
                configureCell(cell: cell as! SwallowCell , model: viewModel.swallowData)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func configureCell(cell: DogCell, model: DogData) {
        
    }
    
    func configureCell(cell: SwallowCell, model: CatData) {
        
    }
    
    func configureCell(cell: SwallowCell, model: SwallowData) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to perform configureCell function outside the cellForRowAt class, I want to not change the cellForRowAt function and still like to add new cells. But, if it is not possible, I will use this methodology.

Comment: The other way to do it would be to use a `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdiffabledatasource) which lets you use a function to create table view cells.